# Executing a pipeline when both a schedule and a second condition is met in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to trigger my pipeline when both a schedule is met and files in a certain folder substructure are changed. So for example: If files somewhere in the folder "SRC" have been changed and it is 10:00am the pipeline shall execute.
I have read some problems on Stack Overflow that seem quite similar, but none of the solutions seems to be working for me. The relevant part of my yaml looks as follows:

```
workflow:
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
        changes:
          - Modultest/Firmware/SRC/**/*
```

The problem is that it always executes on schedule, no matter if the second criterion is met. But not using a dash before "changes" should make "changes" an "AND"-condition, doesn't it?

Comment: You're right that the logical evaluation is `AND` however, you're running into a condition in which `changes:` will always evaluate `true` as answered by Babasile. Additionally, you'll want to check the docs carefully for other limitations of `changes:` (for example limits to number of files checked) to ensure you're not constrained there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `compare_to` in your `changes` because a scheduled pipeline does
not have a `Git push event` so you need to specify the branch to compare it.

The text in [the doc about it](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) and [the doc about `compare_to`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangescompare_to)